# Exporting methods from an angular factory or directive to use later

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, raphael, angularjs-scope

I have developed a web application using Angular.js (It's my first). The application features a collection of interactive graphics (seat maps); so I created a module to handle the Raphael stuff, including a directive, like so:

```
angular.module('raphael', [])
.factory('fillData', function() {
  return function(paper, data) {
    var canvas = $(paper.canvas);

    // Do fill the data and more ...

    canvas.on('click', '[id]', function(e) {
      this.classList.toggle('selected');
    });
  };
})
.directive('raphael', ['fillData',
  function(fillData) {
    return {
      scope: {
        raphael : '&',
        seatData: '&'
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var paper = null;

        var updateSeatData = function() {
          if(scope.seatData()) fillData(paper, scope.seatData());
        };

        scope.$watch(scope.raphael, function() {
          element.empty();
          paper = new Raphael(element[0], '100%', '100%');
          paper.add(scope.raphael());
          updateSeatData();
        });

        scope.$watch(scope.seatData, function() {
          updateSeatData();
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Everything works fine, until it get to the point where we need to interact with the vector in another level. Let's say, getting a count of selected seats, or deselecting all (triggered by some random element in the document).
I don't seem to be able to find a reasonable way of implementing it.

What do you suggest?
Is there any other approach to using a second library inside angular?

Comment: it might help if you could rephrase you question, putting more details into the subject line

Comment: @b1r3k I actually have no idea how to put it in words! I'm not even sure if I'm asking the right question!

Comment: @b1r3k Does that sound better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you want to have directive which have certain internal state but you would like to access it's state from outside (other directive, service, etc.).
If so, then it seems that you could use service as state holder. In such case your directive will not hold state but it will be accessing it.

Comment: Oh, I see. I had forgot the fact that importing a module gives you access to it's providers too!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a reasonable way of implementing it? It looks good, although I would prefer to bind to the attribute seatData instead of passing function like

```
scope: {
  seatData: '='
}
```

And then watch it

```
scope.$watch('seatData', function() {
  fillData(paper, scope.seatData);
});
```

Is this you issue or I haven't understood it?

Comment: "Reasonable way of implementing" the main problem, which is, I need to do stuff with the canvas later. But it's not possible unless I select the element again somewhere else in the code, which is not a good method.

Comment: BTW, what's the difference between watching scope.seatData and 'seatData'? and why do you prefer a two-way binding?

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the solution I came up with; I accessed the parent scope and put essential methods there.

Adding this line to the `fillData` factory:

```
return {
  deselectAll: function() { ... }
};
```

And changed `updateSeatData` method to:

```
var updateSeatData = function() {
  if(scope.seatData) {
    var result = fillData(paper, scope.seatData[scope.level]);
    angular.extend(scope.$parent, result);
  }
};
```

p.s. Still open to hearing more…